# HTML 5 Canvas elements not animating correctly in a .setInterval method

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

The code will render the animation with one of the "boxes" , but acts very strangely when two of the "boxes" are drawn within the `setInterval` method. I suspect this may have something to do with `ctx.clearRect`.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrcruz2014/owhsuq3u/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var raf;
var switchDirection = [true, true];

function alien() {

  if (canvas.getContext) {

    function Spaceships(x) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = 100;
      this.color = 'rgb(192, 192, 192)';

      this.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 100, 100);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
      };
    };

    var alienOne = new Spaceships(100);
    var alienTwo = new Spaceships(500);

    alienOne.draw();
    alienTwo.draw();

    setInterval(function redraw() {

      if (alienOne.x == 200) {
        switchDirection[0] = false;
      } else if (alienOne.x == 100) {
        switchDirection[0] = true;
      }

      if (switchDirection[0] == true) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        alienOne.draw();
        alienOne.x += 10;
      } else if (switchDirection[0] == false) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        alienOne.draw();
        alienOne.x -= 10;
      }

      if (alienTwo.x == 600) {
        switchDirection[1] = false;
      } else if (alienTwo.x == 500) {
        switchDirection[1] = true;
      }

      if (switchDirection[1] == true) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        alienTwo.draw();
        alienTwo.x += 10;
      } else if (switchDirection[1] == false) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        alienTwo.draw();
        alienTwo.x -= 10;
      }

    }, 250);

  } else {
    alert('you need a better browser to play this game')
  }
};
alien();
```

I have tried placing the second box in its own `.setInterval.` The animation   renders incorrectly by not properly adjusting its width.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first, all your call to `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0);` will produce nothing (you are requesting to clear a 0 width * 0 height rectangle of the canvas). Finally, `setInterval` is not a stable timing function. It just tells the browser to wait at least 250ms before executing the callback. For animations, you'd be better with `requestAnimationFrame` which does synchronise with the screen refresh rate. https://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/3tkjjuy7/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. You are right. The clearRect() did not have the correct parameters in them. However I am trying to maintain the "choppy" animation in an attempt to emulate the aliens in space invaders.
https://jsfiddle.net/mrcruz2014/3tkjjuy7/1/
If you notice, the left square will not adjust width accordingly.

Comment: I don't remember that invaders ships grew like that. Don't you want to just clear the whole frame once per frame (https://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/3tkjjuy7/5/)

Comment: Oh, wow. I see what you did there. I would not have thought of that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your problem, and refactored some of your code:

- The main problem was the clearing of the canvas with the `clearRect` method. You didn't specify the right parameter values.
- Some of the code is very repetitive. For now this isn't really a problem since you're only using 2 aliens, however this could become a problem once you have more than two. Imagine writing almost identical code for 40 aliens. This is solved with arrays and `for`-loops. Also, you use a boolean variable to determine when to add/substract from the alienX. This too can become quite a hassle. Now, we check when the spaceships exceed/go below the tolerated x-value, and change the sign of your velocity accordingly.
- As mentioned by [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919147/html-5-canvas-elements-not-animating-correctly-in-a-setinterval-method#comment67124563_39919147) in the comments above, you can use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/request-animation-frame-for-better-performance) for your animations, which is better for this project than `setInterval`. To maintain the *choppy* animation effect, I used a really basic counter, with the `%` operator to only execute the code every 4x in a second (usually, reqAnimFrame callbacks 60x per second, so 60/15 = 4, equal to 250ms in your example) (see below).

**The code:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var aliens = [];
var counter = 0;

function alien() {

  if (canvas.getContext) {

    function Spaceships(x) {
      this.baseX = x; // added a baseX to remember where the spaceship started off
      this.x = x;
      this.y = 100;
      this.velocityX = 10;
      this.color = "rgb(192, 192, 192)";

      this.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 100, 100);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }

    aliens.push(new Spaceships(100), new Spaceships(500));
    drawAllAliens();

    function redraw() {

      requestAnimationFrame(redraw);

      var maxXDiff = 100; //choose how far or near your aliens/squares can go
      counter ++;

      // remainder/modulo operator: 
      // reduce animation to every 4x per sec for that "choppy" animation
      if(counter%15 === 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < aliens.length; i ++) {
          if ( ( (aliens[i].baseX + maxXDiff) < aliens[i].x ) || (aliens[i].baseX > aliens[i].x) ) {
            aliens[i].velocityX = -aliens[i].velocityX; // switches the sign
          }
          aliens[i].x += aliens[i].velocityX;
        }
      }

      drawAllAliens();
    }

    redraw();

    function drawAllAliens() {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

      for (var i = 0; i < aliens.length; i++) {
        aliens[i].draw();
      }
    }

  } else {
    alert("you need a better browser to play this game");
  }
}

alien();
```

Comment: Just a note that requestAnimationFrame (rAF) calls the callback with the first argument time. The time is high precision time (1/1000000th) in ms units (1/1000th) ( same as performance.now() returns) The time is ms since page load. As rAF will wait the full 1/60th frame if it misses one you are much bettor of using the time to set the frame rate (also anecdotally rFA can run at 120fps and higher on some machines)